# Javascript: how to put some value on the textfield data-id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox where I kept a empty textbox so on load of it I want to put some data on the attribute `data-id`

Ex.

I have `<input id='shiftSel' data-id="" style="font-size: 11px; color:#3399FF;  type="text" size="5">`

So on load of page I want to put some some value to `data-id=""` this, how to do this?

I only know how to put value on the textbox value field
Like

```
    $(document).ready(function() { $("#shiftSel").val(dateArr[0]); } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
 $("#shiftSel").attr("data-id",dateArr[0]);
```

or [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) (if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3)

```
$(this).data("id",dateArr[0]);
```

Comment: You're using a **really** old version of jQuery. (Like 4 years old).

Answer (score 1):

Use `.data()`  `--->`  http://api.jquery.com/data/

```
$("#shiftSel").data('id',dateArr[0]);
```

Note : `.data()` is not going to update actual data-id attribute, it just update data associated with your element which is maintained by browser. (*you will not be able to inspect the change in your browser console's element view*)

Answer (score 1):

Or an alternative way you can use `.attr()` also

```
$("#shiftSel").attr("data-id","5");
console.log($("#shiftSel").attr("data-id"));
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/RbAz6/)

Answer (score 0):

use **[data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**:

```
$('#shiftSel').data('id','idvaluehere')
```

Comment: Tested with `$('#shiftSel').data('id','88');` but not working?

Comment: use `alert($('#shiftSel').data('id'))` just after you set the value above.

Answer (score 0):

use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

```
$("#shiftSel").data('id','something here')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

---

From this quote: ***i want to put some some value to data-id=""***

---

```
$("#shiftSel").data('id',' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** .

May be **[data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** does not work with some jquery lib and browser not support HTML5